# Displaying Toaster Errors for Bad Http Requests

Tags: json, angular, typescript, error-handling

I am trying to catch an error thrown by my Web API in Angular, and I want to display a user-friendly error message in certain cases. How would I access the string "PE and Owner Signature must be attached for a status of Submitted", given the response body below?

```
{
  "data": {
    "model.WorkflowStepId": [
      "PE and Owner Signature must be attached for a status of Submitted"
    ]
  },
  "exceptionType": "FieldValidation"
}
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm stuck since I am currently only displaying the string "model.WorkflowSetId".

```
this.spinner = this.certService.updateCert(this.damId, this.certId, this.model)
      .subscribe(response => {
        ...
      }, 
      (errorRes: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (errorRes.error && errorRes.error.exceptionType === 'FieldValidation') {
          const errors = errorRes.error.data;
          for(let error in errors)
            this.notificationService.error(error);
        } else {
          console.log(errorRes);
          this.notificationService.error('An unknown error has occurred. Please try again.');
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply do:

```
if (errorRes.error && errorRes.error.exceptionType === 'FieldValidation') {
   this.notificationService.error(errorRes.error.data.model.WorkflowStepId[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that "model.WorkflowStepId" was actually a string. To capture it and other types of validation errors I was able to loop through bad requests, build a string that grouped the same types of field validation errors into single messages, and display those messages to the user using the toaster.

```
if (errorRes.error && errorRes.error.exceptionType === 'FieldValidation') {
    for (var key in errorRes.error.data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < errorRes.error.data[key].length; i++) {
            errorStr += (errorRes.error.data[key][i]);
            errorStr += ". ";
        }    
        this.notificationService.error(errorStr);
    }
}
```